# Run custom protocol based on selection box in windows toast notification

Tags: xml, windows, powershell, uwp, toast

I have previosly created a script that launches custom toast notification with buttons launching scripts via custom Classes/Protocols. Now i wanted to make it prettier and included a SelectionBox.
I am unable to run those custom protocols based on Selected item. Please advise

```
$ToastTitle = ""
$Signature = ""
$BannerImage = 'C:\Users\anowak\OneDrive - Phlexglobal Ltd\Desktop\Personal\Scripts\Toast\lake.jpg'
$EventTitle = "Testing Title"
$EventText = "This is where there would normally be info. This is just a test though."
$site = "http://google.com/"
$MoreInfoTitle = "More Information"
$Snooze = $true
$CustomHello = "Hello $env:USERNAME"


#Specify Launcher App ID, the App that will claim ownership of the toast notification, doesn't affect functionality.
$LauncherID = '{1AC14E77-02E7-4E5D-B744-2EB1AE5198B7}\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe'

#Load Assemblies
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager, Windows.UI.Notifications, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
[Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument, ContentType = WindowsRuntime] | Out-Null
 
#Build XML Template
[xml]$toastTemplate = @"
<toast duration="long" scenario="reminder">
    <visual>
        <binding template="ToastGeneric">
            <text>$CustomHello</text>
            <text>$ToastTitle</text>
            <text placement="attribution">$Signature</text>
            <image placement="hero" src="$BannerImage"/>
            <group>
                <subgroup>
                    <text hint-style="title" hint-wrap="true" >$EventTitle</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
            <group>
                <subgroup>
                    <text hint-style="body" hint-wrap="true" >$EventText</text>
                </subgroup>
            </group>
        </binding>
    </visual>
     <actions>
        <input id="MySelection" type="selection" title="Choose:" defaultInput="1">
            <selection id="1" content="Zenek:"/>
            <selection id="2" content="NetExt"/>
            <selection id="3" content="Shorts"/>
            <selection id="4" content="Busy"/>
            <selection id="5" content="Time"/>
        </input>
        <action activationType="protocol" arguments="WHAT DO I PUT HERE" hint-inputId="MySelection" content="RUN"/>
        <action arguments="dismiss" content="" activationType="system"/>
    </actions>
</toast>
"@


#Prepare XML
$ToastXml = [Windows.Data.Xml.Dom.XmlDocument]::New()
$ToastXml.LoadXml($ToastTemplate.OuterXml)
$ToastMessage = [Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotification]::New($ToastXML)
[Windows.UI.Notifications.ToastNotificationManager]::CreateToastNotifier($LauncherID).Show($ToastMessage)
```

Comment: Perhaps [this article](https://toastit.dev/2020/08/07/actionable/) can help

Comment: I've seen this article before, and was hoping that not to be the case. I am working in PS5 with no ability to update to 7 or install modules. This unfortunatelly means I'm stuck with button only.